# AWS S3 authentification from windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pentaho

I am using Pentaho (8.1) from windows environment (remote desktop).
To Upload files to S3 I am using config & credential files.
When I use default file location in %USERPROFILE%.aws\config and %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials it works fine.

I don't want every user to manually handle credentials file, so I would like to use same location for all users.
I have set environment variables:

AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE D:\data.aws\credentials

AWS_CONFIG_FILE D:\data.aws\config

But looks like it doesn't pick up this location correctly.

I am sure that files in %USERPROFILE% are actually used. I have also done full restart after changing variables, but it doesn't help.

Is there something I am missing from configuration?

Comment: Have you checked if users actually have permissions for that folder?

Comment: There are no access restrictions to D: drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to set environment variables, then you can simply put the credentials in environment variables for each user:

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`